# How to use @Transcational with spring-data-cosmosdb?

Tags: spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb

I am using `spring-data-cosmosdb` library in my project and I am unable to create `@Transcational` method because there is no `TransactionManager` or `DataSource` defined in my context. Does this API supports transactional methods at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cosmos DB itself doesn't have transactions that span more than one operation. The only transactional operation in Cosmos DB is via a stored procedure, where all operations that take place within that stored procedure succeed or fail as a transaction (and these are scoped to a single partition within a single collection).

This is likely why you cannot use `@transactional`.

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55447997/272109).

Comment: FYI, as mentioned in the linked-to answer in my answer, both the .NET and Java SDK support Transactional Batch now. Not sure if `@Transactional` behavior has changed now, though.