# Spring Data cosmos @Transactions support

Tags: java, spring, azure, spring-data-jpa, azure-cosmosdb

With [Azure Cosmos DB transactional batch support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-cosmos-db-transactional-batch-support-for-java-sdk-470-and-above/) available for Cosmos Java SDK 4.7.0, Does Spring Data Cosmos allows transactional operations?

I went through [Spring Data Cosmos Github Documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-spring-data-cosmos), but didn't find a reference.

Need help if there is a way to implement transaction batch operations via spring cosmos data. If there is no way currently, then what would be the best way to proceed ?

Comment: You can refer to [How to use @Transcational with spring-data-cosmosdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61590493/how-to-use-transcational-with-spring-data-cosmosdb). You can open an issue on GitHub: [azure-sdk-for-java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactional batch is not supported via Spring data Cosmos. As an alternative, you can access CosmosClient from within a Spring application to leverage transactional batch capabilities.