# Need to update multiple collection of cosmosdb with spring boot. How to manage the transaction. If anything failed all should be rolled back

Tags: spring-boot, transactions, azure-cosmosdb

How to handle transaction using spring boot and cosmosdb. For example write has to made in mutiple collections, if anyone of them fails then all should be rolled back. It is written in this link that its possible with version 4 api.
[How to handle Transaction in CosmosDB - "All or nothing" concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55447997/how-to-handle-transaction-in-cosmosdb-all-or-nothing-concept)

Any integration example will be helpful.

Comment: This is not a specific question. Please search for a tutorial how to use spring boot with cosmosdb. If you run into any specific problems and have a specific error message then you're welcome to ask a question here.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Cosmos does not support transactions across containers. Transactions are scoped to a single logical partition only.